# Model object has no attribute - Tortoise ORM

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'GuildCluster' object has no attribute 'guilds'` when I try to get the `guilds` attribute (which is a ReverseRelation fields) from a `GuildCluster` object.

I already tried to check the relations, the foreign keys, to rename the attribute in case it was already used. I also tried to define the `Guild` class before `GuildCluster`, it returns the same error.

Here is the `GuildCluster` model (a part of it):

```
class GuildCluster(Model):
    class Meta:
        table = "guild_clusters"

    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)

    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)

    infos: fields.ReverseRelation["ClusterInfo"]
    guilds: fields.ReverseRelation["Guild"]
    users: fields.ReverseRelation["User"]
```

And here is the `Guild` model (a part of it too):

```
class Guild(Model):
    class Meta:
        table = "guilds"

    id = fields.BigIntField(pk=True)
    cluster = fields.ForeignKeyField("main.GuildCluster", related_name="cluster_guilds")

    infos: fields.ReverseRelation["GuildInfo"]
```

You can note that the `infos` and `users` attribute are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was caused by this line in `Guild` : `cluster = fields.ForeignKeyField("main.GuildCluster", related_name="cluster_guilds")`.

If you want to access to the related fields of a Model, you have to use the name that you set in the `ForeignKeyField`.

So here, to make the previous code work you have to call `<GuildCluster>.cluster_guilds` or change `related_name="cluster_guilds"` to `related_name="guilds"`